# Construct a grammar that generates the language $L = \{ a^x b^{x-y} c^y \mid x > y > 0 \text{ and } (x + y) \text{ is even }\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammar

I have the following problem:

> Construct a grammar that only generates the strings that belong to the language $L$ where:
>   $$
> L = \{ a^x b^{x-y} c^y \mid x > y > 0 \text{ and }(x + y) \text{ is even} \}
> $$

From which I deduced that:

1. $x$ and $y$ have to both be either odd or even for their sum to be even.

But how to I proceed in generating the grammar. This language is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the type of grammar (see Chomsky hierarchy)?

Comment: @supinf No such restriction is defined in the problem.

Comment: Note that $x>y$ in your problem statement. Hence it is not possible that $x=y$ (as you said in 2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i found a context-free grammar that does this.
Let $S$ be the start symbol.

1. $S \to aQc$
2. $Q \to aQc$
3. $Q \to aaRbb$
4. $R \to aaRbb$
5. $R \to \epsilon$.

Some explanations: 1. is to ensure that $y>0$, there has to be at least one $c$.
2. Increase both $x$ and $y$ by $1$.
3. Increase $x$ by 2, ensuring that there is at least one $b$ (because $x>y$).
4. Increase $x$ by 2, if necessary. We cannot increase by one, because $x,y$ need to have the same parity.